# Clean up the code of a GTKmm application

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I started a GTKMM application about 6 months ago and it's reached the point where everything works and I actually use it daily. It's essentially a database application that reads in data files from another application, generates graphs and lets you easily sort and view the data. I like it.

HOWEVER, I believe my code is a mess and when I went to implement another feature today I realized that I probably made a wrong turn somewhere.

My main window GUI is defined in a glade file and ALL of the GUI (other than my plot widget which is a custom widget based on a Gtk::DrawingArea) is in a single file. It is FULL of pointers to widgets and treestores that all get setup in the constructor and deleted in the destructor.

The entire GUI is a main window split into different panes so it made sense to have everything in 1 file. Also, different panes need to "communicate" with other panes.

How should I better organize my code so that it is maintainable?  Do I make a new class that is essentially a collection of widgets and then place that "super widget" in my main window (say each pane is a super widget)?

GTKMM tutorials are generally very minimalistic so I couldn't get much insight there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I currently work on a large GTKMM application.  The general rule that is followed throughout the codebase is that each Frame (containing a collection of widgets) is its own class in its own cpp file.  These classes are then instantiated in the main function as singleton classes each exposing a getFrame method.

```
// Single instance of this class.
SomeGUIComponent* SomeGUIComponent::m_instance = NULL;

SomeGUIComponent& SomeGUIComponent::getInstance()
{
  if (m_instance == NULL)
  {
    m_instance = new SomeGUIComponent();
  }
  return *m_instance;
}

Gtk::Frame& SomeGUIComponent::getFrame()
{
  return m_myMasterFrame;
}
```

So this can be added to the larger application with:

```
SomeGUIComponent::getInstance().getFrame()
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Now, what about when frames need to talk to each other?  For example, if you press a button in SomeGUIComponentA and you need to refresh a label in SomeGUIComponentB?  Right now since both the button and label are in my huge GUI class it is trivial, but will each frame need to have a point to every other frame then?

Comment: @baubie, in this case we would expose a public method in Component B to update the private label and from ComponentA call: SomeGUIComponentB.getInstance().updateLabel(valueToUpdateWith);

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I've been doing a lot of reading about this since posting the question.  Your answer is certainly valid so I've marked it as such.  THe only downside is that singletons seem to be getting highly discouraged for the same reason as global variables.  Instead, I think I might pass a pointer to the parent window to each component and call components through the parent.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I ended up doing was to separate each logical collection of widgets into their own class. Then I create signals that were caught in my master GUI class and dealt with there.  Anything that has to be passed around is done in the master GUI class code but now things make sense.  For example, I don't care of a particular combobox value changed in my Filter frame.  Instead, I'm interested when the Filter changed, period.  So my filter class (containing all the filter widgets) throws a custom changed() signal and I have setters and getters for the variables in that filter which then updates the widgets appropriately.

I think this way is very clean, avoids singletons, compartmentalizes my UI and makes things overall way nicer to work with.